# Why is Ubuntu One slow to sync in 11.10, either backup or any sub-folder contents?

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one, sync, deja-dup

I have been trying to sync my documents folder of 1.4GB, it still hasn't worked and it has been syncing for a month. The top level syncs, files and folders in the Document folders, but contents of sub-folders just hang. (Gave up and stopped syncing this folder)

However,I have tried using the backup facility in 11.10, to backup to Ubuntu One.... I upgraded my HDD space in Ubuntu One. It has been going now for 24hours-ish and only backed up what looks like a couple of percent.

(By the way what an excellent idea to backup to Ubuntu One, if only we could get it to actually work! :-o)

The odd thing is I can sync to drop box within hours, rather than months.

This is bad, and has been an issue since Ubuntu One's release. I have reported this problem and there were promises in later releases this would be fixed, but it hasn't.

Canonical cannot help either... I posted on several blogs, a lot of people have the same problem but no fixes.

So do I use dropbox or another service, until it is sorted, as Ubuntu does not seem to see this as an issue, I think a fix will be a long time in coming.

(However,I love the potential of Ubuntu One and the integration with the OS)

Yes my internet speeds are fine, etc... :-) No firewall (sudo ufw status: STATUS: INACTIVE), No Proxy, etc

NB:
I have raised this as a separate question to others posted here, because my question relates to Ubuntu 11.10, though I have commented elsewhere for help. Plus my question also relates to deja-dup backup to Ubuntu One.

Thanks

Comment: In general, you should ask questions here. For bugs use launchpad.net. For support to a paid service contact the service provider. Do not use blogs for questions, nor askubuntu for rants.

Comment: Rants? Seriously m8! I am trying to find a problem to a fault. I am trying to sync but it is extremely slooooow, fact not rant. I am after a solution, ubuntu One is an integral part of Ubuntu, therefore this is a relevant question. However, no-one anywhere seems to have found a solution. I mention dropbox because it shows that there is no problem with my internet speeds....

Comment: So where do I go for help?

Comment: Have you ask here https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/ for help, since this service is provided by canonical? What did they tell you with regard to your problem?

Comment: Sorry, I thought Ubuntu and Canonical were one of the same... guess not.... I have contacted one.ubuntu.com/help/contact as suggested... hopefully they will help. If I get an answer I will post here.. Thanks

Comment: I'm also sorry, I did not want to be rude with my comments... If you ask on askubuntu, you will receive answers from the Ubuntu community, people like me, who answer some questions just to help others. The UbuntuOne service is however purely a Canonical thing and they have paid staff who will try to help you with UbuntuOne specific things. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Ubuntu One, and they were very helpful.

They suggested I tried the following:

Press Alt-F2, type "gnome-terminal", press "Enter" and run:

u1sdtool -q

sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/ubuntuone

u1sdtool -c

Let that go for at least 30 minutes.

Files have started to transfer, seems to be going ok.... will monitor

....still slow to sync sub folders and files